# How to setup SSL certificate for GCP instance which uses nginx, gunicorn and flask?

Tags: ssl, nginx, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have created a flask app which uses sockets. It is run by gunicorn and uses nginx servers. 
I need to create SSL certificate for my instance. If I follow this link:
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssl-certificates/create
the command

`gcloud compute ssl-certificates create NAME --certificate=LOCAL_FILE_PATH --private-key=LOCAL_FILE_PATH [--description=DESCRIPTION] [GCLOUD_WIDE_FLAG …]`

What should I do to create/get files on local that is used in the above command?

Answer (score 1):

To create SSL certificates for your Compute Engine instance you can follow the document "[Creating and Using SSL Certificates](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates#creating_an_ssl_certificate_resource)", it has step by step instructions on how to create the SSL certificates.

Once you have created the files using the Cloud Shell, you can download them by clicking in the  three dots at the top left side of the Cloud Shell window, then select the "Download file" option, you will be prompted to enter the full path of the file.